# How to change cache expire time ? spring boot authorization server

Tags: spring, caching, server, authorization, boot

How to change cache expire time ? spring boot authorization server

spring boot authorization server version : 1.1.1

After just 5 minutes, the resource server returns 401.
Results of searching documents related to 5 minutes
When using cache in nimbus decode on the resource server, 5 minutes is the default value.
How can I change this?
And can I change it only on the resource server?

Token, session, and cookie are all fine. I think only cache problem.

Answer (score 0):

In a Spring Boot authorization server, you can configure the expiration time for access tokens and refresh tokens.

Try this:

```
# Access token validity period in seconds
 security.oauth2.authorizationserver.token.access-token-validity-seconds=3600

# Refresh token validity period in seconds
 security.oauth2.authorizationserver.token.refresh-token-validity-seconds=86400
```

--
So check the documentation for a specific version of Spring Boot Authorization.